# Tomcat shows blank page - GWT devmode works fine

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, tomcat

I am developing a GWT project on eclipse, and when I run the Development Mode everything works fine. But when I deploy the WAR file (generated following this guide [click](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/)) on my tomcat server, `http://localhost:8080/myproj/` shows only a blank page.
I tried to add `Window.alert("..")` as first line in `onModuleLoad()` method and it DOES show correctly.
Clearing browser-cache was useless.
Server startup executes without problems nor exceptions.
What should I do to solve this problem?

This is my entry point class

```
public class Segnalazioni_Degrado implements EntryPoint {

protected static List<Macrocategoria> listaMacrocategorie;
protected static List<Segnalazione> segnalazioniAttiveCached = new ArrayList<Segnalazione>();
protected static List<SegnalazioneRisolta> segnalazioniRisolteCached = new ArrayList<SegnalazioneRisolta>();

protected static final DataLayerServiceAsync dataLayerService = GWT
        .create(DataLayerService.class);
protected static final LoginServiceAsync loginService = GWT
        .create(LoginService.class);
protected static final MailServiceAsync mailService = GWT
        .create(MailService.class);

protected static Properties props;
private final String TITOLO = "PORTALE SEGNALAZIONI DEGRADO";

private LatLng romaLatLng;

private DockLayoutPanel mainPnl;

private HorizontalPanel northPnl;
private HorizontalPanel southPnl;
private VerticalPanel westPnl;
private AbsolutePanel centerPnl;

protected static StatsPanel statsPnl;
protected static MenuPanel menuPnl;
protected static LoginPanel loginPnl;
protected static LegendPanel legendPnl;

protected static MapWidget map;
private Label titoloLbl;
private/* Button */FocusWidget areaRiservataBtn;
private Button followUsOnTwitterBtn;
private HTML mailto;

/**
 * TODO tweet segnalazione inserita o risolta, porta su .css tutto il
 * possibile, prendi tutto da config, fai log su server, crea mail, leggenda
 * icone, elimina file foto non solo link
 */

public void onModuleLoad() {
    loadProps();
    buildUI();
}

void loadProps() {
    props.set("scarsa manutenzione manto stradale", "images/red.png");
    props.set("veicolo abbandonato", "images/red.png");
    props.set("discarica abusiva", "images/green.png");
    props.set("accumulo spazzatura", "images/green.png");
}

void buildUI() {
    Maps.loadMapsApi("", "2", false, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            buildHomePage();
        }
    });
}

private void buildHomePage() {

    mainPnl = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PCT);
    mainPnl.setStyleName("mainPanel");
    northPnl = new HorizontalPanel();
    northPnl.setStyleName("northPanel");
    southPnl = new HorizontalPanel();
    southPnl.setStyleName("southPanel");
    westPnl = new VerticalPanel();
    westPnl.setStyleName("westPanel");
    centerPnl = new AbsolutePanel();
    centerPnl.setStyleName("centerPnl");

    loginPnl = new LoginPanel();
    statsPnl = new StatsPanel();
    menuPnl = new MenuPanel();

    Segnalazioni_Degrado.dataLayerService
    .getListaMacrocategorie(new AsyncCallback<List<Macrocategoria>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            caught.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Macrocategoria> result) {

            Segnalazioni_Degrado.listaMacrocategorie = result;
            centerPnl.add(new LegendPanel());
        }

    });


    /**
     * costruisco la Google Map
     */
    Size mapSize = Size.newInstance(500, 500);
    MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.newInstance();
    mapOpts.setSize(mapSize);
    romaLatLng = LatLng.newInstance(41.8902624, 12.4923096);
    map = new MapWidget(romaLatLng, 12, mapOpts);
    map.checkResizeAndCenter();
    map.setSize("99%", "99%");
    map.addControl(new LargeMapControl());
    map.setDoubleClickZoom(true);
    map.setScrollWheelZoomEnabled(true);
    map.setStyleName("map");

    /**
     * costruisco il titolo del portale
     */
    titoloLbl = new Label(TITOLO);
    titoloLbl.setStyleName("titolo");

    /**
     * costruisco bottone per accedere ad area riservata
     */
    /* areaRiservataBtn = new Button("Accedi all'area riservata"); */
    areaRiservataBtn = new Button("AREA RISERVATA");
    areaRiservataBtn.setStyleName("bottomBtn");
    areaRiservataBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            new AreaRiservataDialog();
        }
    });

    /**
     * costruisco bottone twitter
     */

    followUsOnTwitterBtn = new Button();

    followUsOnTwitterBtn.addStyleName("bottomBtn");
    followUsOnTwitterBtn.addStyleName("twitter");


    followUsOnTwitterBtn
            .getElement()
            .appendChild(
                    new HTML(
                            "<div><img src=images/twitter.gif><b>segui @stop_degrado</b></div>")
                            .getElement());
    followUsOnTwitterBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.open("https://twitter.com/stop_degrado", "_blank", "");
        }

    });

    /**
     * costruisco bottone mailto
     */
    mailto = new HTML("<a href=mailto:dummy@fake.foo> Contattaci </a>");
    mailto.setStyleName("bottomBtn");

    /**
     * creo bottone ABOUT US
     */
    Button aboutus = new Button("ABOUT US");
    aboutus.setStyleName("bottomBtn");
    aboutus.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            new AboutUsPopup();
        }

    });



    northPnl.add(titoloLbl);
    northPnl.add(loginPnl);

    westPnl.add(menuPnl);

    westPnl.add(statsPnl);

    southPnl.add(followUsOnTwitterBtn);
    southPnl.add(aboutus);
    southPnl.add(areaRiservataBtn);
    southPnl.add(mailto);

    centerPnl.add(map);


    mainPnl.addNorth(northPnl, 8);
    mainPnl.addWest(westPnl, 30);
    mainPnl.addSouth(southPnl, 3.5);
    mainPnl.add(centerPnl);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(mainPnl);

    MenuPanel.refreshBtn.click();

}
}
```

Comment: Try to activate logging: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html And check the browsers javascript-console.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I'm not sure which events I should log..BTW, chrome seems to properly load segnalazioni_degrado.nocache.js

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I just noticed that the console on Chrome says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'zd' of null

Comment: That means you have a NullPointer. Try to compile in DETAILED. This will preserve the method an variable names. Maybe you'll have luck and  get the correct piece of code. The strange thig ist, that you don't have the problem in DevMode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a `NullPointer`:

```
protected static Properties props; // << NULL

public void onModuleLoad() {
    loadProps(); // props is still NULL
    buildUI();
}

void loadProps() {
    // props is still NULL
    props.set("scarsa manutenzione manto stradale", "images/red.png"); // BANG!
[...]
```

By the way:
Why did you make `props` static? There is only one instance of you EntryPoint. So no state can be shared.

Comment: You were right, thank you very much. How come no NullPointerException was thrown when executing in development mode? It would have been much easier to find the problem..

Comment: I have no idea, why the NPE did not happen in DevMode. Maybe you set the staic variable once and did not retart the DevMode.